Why do many PhD application sites for US universities prevent recommenders from updating recommendation letters, even before the application deadline?
I've noticed that many PhD application sites for US universities prevent recommenders from updating the recommendation letters, even before the application deadline. Why?
Example:


Hmmm. Sick of dealing with too many bad documents and the necessary communication that it requires? Guessing. Are you sure it is "many"?

@Buffy >50% in the 20 univs I've done this year (CS departments). Updating a PDF on a site requires no communication, and if sick of dealing with too many bad documents then better allow updating them to fix mistakes.

Surely because they don't want to have to check for updates every day? Be able to make decisions based on a stable situation? It's not like they don't tell you that when you "commit", you can't change it... they do.

@paulgarrett but why prevent even before the application deadline? Don't they decide after the application deadline?

A good point, but, still, some people try to "get a jump on things" before the deadline, to spread the work out over a longer time... as opposed to having to figure things out in a huge rush over the winter holidays, etc. Simplicity?

One should not assume that these systems are administered by people who care about graduate admissions.

Is it possible that a number of R1 universities have agreed to unify their procedures as they have generally done with deadlines?

Consider that it's the other way around. The minimum effort functionality is a system that allows a single submission. Allowing updates is more complex, so unless someone specifically asks and pays for it, the ability to update isn't going to be added.

@user1937198 I think that's exactly it. Probably it didn't even start with this alert, because the people creating the application software never even considered someone would want to update, they're just making a form that accepts a PDF. Then some rare person complained that they wanted to update, and their fix to the software was to add a notice that you can't do that.

Now you have me wondering why that would even be necessary. Just about every recommendation letter I wrote or got was about a long timeline and many interactions, adding another semester wouldn’t have significantly changed things. Are you wondering this just because of the notice (which would underline this isn’t necessary) or would you actually and often have use for updates?

@MisterMiyagi for example if one has forgotten about an important point

This is most likely a technical limitation rather than a policy decision.  I doubt that most admissions committees care one way or another whether recommenders can update their letters through the admission portal, and so many admission portal systems simply don't bother to include an update feature.  The "you may not edit" message is simply to advise you of this, to encourage you to double check your letter before uploading it.
On a practical level, if as a recommender you have an important reason to update your letter (e.g. you uploaded the wrong document, or your letter contains major errors, or something important happened with the student after your letter was submitted), you should contact the admission committee directly, e.g. by emailing the graduate chair or department chair.  You can generally find their email addresses on the department's web page.  However, since this will require some manual intervention on their part, you shouldn't do it just to make minor corrections (e.g. spelling) that don't significantly change your overall recommendation.
